nvidia NIM k8s on prem image deployment
I am trying to install an endpoing which will generate vector from a string using AI model.
Model i am using is from Huggingface intfloat/multilingual-e5-small.
I have simple code like below
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from fastapi.openapi.docs import get_swagger_ui_html
import uvicorn


app = FastAPI()

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
app = FastAPI()
m2 = 'intfloat/multilingual-e5-small'
model = SentenceTransformer(m2, device='cuda')
class EmbeddingRequest(BaseModel):
    sentences: str
@app.post("/embeddings")
async def get_embeddings(request: EmbeddingRequest):
    embeddings = model.encode(request.sentences)
    return embeddings.tolist()[0]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

This is my docker file.
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:24.08-py3
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY src/search-llm-svc.py ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "search-llm-svc.py"]

in one of the k8s deployment this is my resource provision
esources:
  limits:
    cpu: '32'
    ephemeral-storage: 30Gi
    memory: 12Gi
    nvidia.com/gpu: '1'
  requests:
    cpu: '4'
    ephemeral-storage: 3Gi
    memory: 8Gi
    nvidia.com/gpu: '1'

when i build my docker file and deploy on k8s cluster i get below error.
message: >-
failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI
runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container
process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error
running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr:
nvidia-container-cli.real: initialization error: nvml error:
driver/library version mismatch: unknown
This is my node information.
NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.03              Driver Version: 560.35.03      CUDA Version: 12.6
My GPU is type : NVIDIA A30
My basic research says that pytorch:24.08-py3 supports cuda version 12.6 and driver version Driver Version: 560.35.03, i am not sure which configuration is off to get my application successfully deployed.
Let me know if you need more information.

Are you able to run the image in docker? I mean after building the image, run the image with docker run, does that works?
